# Using contains to not look at children

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to filter out and hide divs that don't contain a specific string, but I only care about the

Is there a way to use the contains selector on an element but ignore its children?

Example:

```
<div class="accessBox">Hello
 <ul> 
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Then I would execute:

```
$('.accessBox').filter(":not(:contains('1'))").hide();
```

My goal would be to hide the div

Comment: care about the, umm, what?

Comment: @Alnitak About immediate children

Comment: I'm not sure why j08961 deleted his answer. It works around your problem http://jsfiddle.net/r83A9/

Comment: "g, but I only care about the"..... You forgot to end your sentence.

Comment: No you cannot make `:contains` look only at immediate children. You can work around it by changing your selector to look only at the `<li>`s as some have posted

Comment: @JuanMendes or by using `.contents()` ...

Comment: @Juan Mendes ah, I think I see what you think the question means, which that isn't what I've answered, but would easily adapt to it

Comment: @Alnitak That's the kind of answer I was going to post, but I didn't  since another workaround had already been suggested which I preferred

Comment: Lousy question as written, not least since there's actually an intermediate `<ul>` between the given selector and the `<li>` elements that contain the text he's interested in.

Comment: @Alnitak Lousy is a strong word. I do agree that the question is not well asked. Does the OP really want to hide the `div`? Or is it the `li`s?

Comment: @Juan Mendes: From the question: `"My goal would be to hide the div"`. Their sample code also reflects that. Although I should point out the original code actually does that correctly http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r83A9/9/), so who knows? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I know it says that, but like you pointed out, it was working, so there's something not right about what's being asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
$('.accessBox').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("li:contains('1')").length === 0;
}).hide();
```

[**Concept Verification Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/843v5/)

Comment: It's a slight variation of http://stackoverflow.com/a/25083878/227299 which does work (as I understood the question)

Comment: The goal is to hide the `div` not the `li` or `ul`. To call this a slight variation of what you've provided clearly  shows we are reading from different scripts: "**My goal would be to hide the div**"

Comment: While it looks like it should work, I see a Syntax error `unrecognized expression: li:contains('1'))` when I try this in a JSFiddle. You have one too many `")"`:)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie, thanks!! Caught it too when I was weaving the demo.

Comment: @user3558931 +1 I did misread the code. If the OP does want to remove the div that does not contain a 1, this does work. I'm just not sure that is what the OP wants to do

Comment: You have chosen to interpret the question the same way I did (with the same results), however the original code also works that way too: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r83A9/9/ so who knows what they actually want? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul li').filter(":not(:contains('1'))").hide();
```

Comment: Its pretty straight here. we are using contains selector to filter LI

Comment: No it isn't. There's a reason your code works and the OP's doesn't. You haven't explained it. Newbies will not know why it works and will blindly change their code

Comment: this is a right answer... it should not be down voted

Comment: @AamirShahzad It's a democracy, upvote it. I downvoted it because I don't think it explains why it works

Comment: This does not hide the `div` (which I gather is the aim). It hides individual `LI`s instead.

Comment: Who on Earth flagged my comment on this? I was just pointing out (with a JSFiddle) that this does not appear to do what the OP asked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and `.filter()` to examine just the immediate `TextNode` children of an element:

```
$('.accessBox').filter(function() {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        if (this.nodeType !== 3) return false;  // 3 === Node.TEXT_NODE
        return this.nodeValue.match(/1/);
    }).length > 0;
}).hide();
```

The above works without caring what type of nodes the children themselves are, so is more generic than using a structure-specific selector.

Comment: You might want to try your code with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/843v5/1/ It does not appear to be working.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie OK - one typo (.matches instead of .match) and code that correctly identifies if a specific node contains a text node with that content, but doesn't look at its element children (or grandchildren, given the way the question is asked - it's hard to tell).  Until the question is clarified I'm not going to waste any more time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:has` to test for descendants/values without changing the "current" element from the div:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r83A9/2/

```
$(".accessBox:not(:has(li:contains('1')))").hide();
```

This equates to "find all elements with class .`accessBox` which do not have any `li`s that contain the value 1".

*Given the ambiguous wording of the question, I am happy to adjust this if better sample HTML is shown :)*

Comment: that examines all descendents of the `li`, not the actual text contents of the li.

Comment: @Alnitak: Which does not matter for the data shown.

Comment: The OP said he wanted to ignore the children - it just happens he didn't show any in the DOM.  It's a poor question :(

Comment: The question is not that clear, it's hard to tell what the OP wants